# First batch, followed instructions, not sure if it's going to turn out

Tags: beginner

I am just starting out with homebrewing and I decided for my first batch to use an extract kit from http://www.ontariobeerkegs.com. For my first batch I figured I would follow the instructions to a T. http://www.ontariobeerkegs.com/v/vspfiles/assets/images/3gal%20-%20american%20ipa.pdf. 
I ended up with a very cloudy wort. The instructions however, did not mention anything about filtering or straining and i simply poured my cooled kettle of wort into the fermentation bucket, and sprinkled the dry yeast on top as instructed on the package of yeast.

This was a couple days ago, the airlock is bubbling like crazy (so I assume it's fermenting alright) but after finishing up I was a little unsure of the process that I just completed and I looked up some more details. Mainly to either strain the wort or do the "whirlpool" to leave out much of the gunk. Also i looked up more detailed instructions for the yeast (US-05), that said I should re-hydrate the yeast prior to pitching.

Now i'm worried that I've done something wrong and the beer wont turn out. I guess the only way to know for sure is to wait a few weeks before bottling.

Additional question:
Will it be possible to clarify the beer at the bottling phase or will I be stuck with a cloudy beer. I assume most of the residue will settle and I will be incredibly careful not to disturb during transfer to bottling bucket.

Thanks

James

Comment: Here is a fun fact @Gingerbeardman; the more you brew and the more you learn, the more you will go "wow! I should be doing this in a different/better way". This progression of "doing it better next time" is what leads more home breweries to go from a pot and a bucket to a system with pumps and tubes and a good collection of scientific looking jugs! :) Your beer should be fine. Enjoy the process, learn and make better beer each time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the end of the world if you don't re-hydrate the yeast.

The sediment will settle out over the next couple of weeks.

Don't worry, the beer will be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I think i just needed to hear it from someone else to settle my nerves a bit. Thanks

Comment: I would add that the fact that you had a lot of initial activity is a sign that you've already got a successful, drinkable beer. All the stuff after that point doesn't really "ruin" it, just are opportunities to improve the beer by clarification, aging, bottling...etc

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said, I see no reason to worry.  You said that you followed the instruction to the letter. That's what you're supposed to do.

Now, your cloudiness issue:  I'm going to assume that you like your beer cold.  After you've bottled your beer (be sure to use the included priming sugar), and allowed the 2 week carbonation time, you'll put the bottles into the refrigerator to get cold.  Here's what's going to happen next... you're going to pour the cold beer into a glass carefully, leaving the last 1/8" of beer in to bottom of the bottle.  Then you're going to enjoy it.  It will be clear, unless wheat was in the recipe.

TL;DR
Continue following the instructions and enjoy the beer that you made.  In fact, after you've enjoyed the first one, invite a friend over and the 2 of you can enjoy a beer together.